# Django cannot login using login()

Tags: python, django, authentication

I'm trying to create a login page using `login()` and `authenticate()`, but when I submit the username and password, the user doesn't get authenticated (`is_authenticated = False`), same as if I submit wrong password and/or username.

views.py :

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext
from whitesnake.forms import RegistrationForm, LoginForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from whitesnake.models import Whitesnake
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout

def WhitesnakeLogin(request):
if request.user.is_authenticated():
    return render_to_response('index.html', None, context_instance = RequestContext(request))
if request.method =='POST':
    login_form = LoginForm(request.POST)
    if login_form.is_valid():
        username = login_form.cleaned_data['username']
        password = login_form.cleaned_data['password']
        whitesnake = authenticate(username = username, password = password)
        if whitesnake is not None:
            login(request, whitesnake)
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/admin/')
        else:
            login_form = LoginForm()
            context = {'login_form' : login_form}
            return render_to_response('index.html', context, context_instance = RequestContext(request))
    else:
        login_form = LoginForm()
        context = {'login_form' : login_form}
        return render_to_response('index.html', context, context_instance = RequestContext(request))        
else:
    login_form = LoginForm()
    context = {'login_form' : login_form}
    return render_to_response('index.html', context, context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

forms.py :

```
from django import forms
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from whitesnake.models import Whitesnake

class LoginForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.EmailField(label=(u'Username'))
    password = forms.CharField(label=(u'Password'), widget = forms.PasswordInput(render_value = False))
```

i already made a register page and I'm make sure that the username and the password i use are correct and already stored in MySQL. Whitesnake is the name of the user app

Comment: "It doesn't work" is the most useless thing you can post here. *What* doesn't work? What do you see that you shouldn't? What don't you see that you should? What errors do you get?

Comment: If you're not already doing so, run it using the debug server Django provides (``python manage.py runserver``), and see what messages that spits out.

Comment: Insert a `print` or `logging` statement just after every decision you make in your `WhitesnakeLogin` view (after every `if` and `else` statement) and then paste in the logs here. For example, after `if login_form.is_valid():` insert a print statement e.g. `print "Login form is valid."`. That way you can determine what your view is doing when, rather than just saying "it doesn't work".

Comment: And for extra bonus points: if you use `logging` statements you can install `django-debug-toolbar` and then easily view all the logs that come out when you render a view. The combination of `logging` statements and `django-debug-toolbar`, ideally while writing unit tests, is a powerful and efficient way to develop views. For an example refer to a toy Django app I'm writing here: https://github.com/asimihsan/djangokata/tree/master/imageupload

Comment: "fyi, i already made a register page and I'm make sure that the username and the password i use are correct and already stored in MySQL". Django stores hashed passwords, it does not store passwords as plaintext. What does your MySQL users table row actually look like? Did you add the user via Django or did you add the row yourself? Post this as well please. More info here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#how-django-stores-passwords